# Categorization of the text with multiple keywords in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to categorize my **Description** based on the **Keywords** and mention its **Type** in the **Output Category**

This can be seen below with an example. There are certain keywords with the type and I want the output category filled with the Type corresponding to the Description

[image]

[image]

With the help of the below function,

=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(1,IFNA(MATCH("asterisk"'&K:K&"asterisk",A2,0),0),0))

I can achieve the required result in B2 and B3 cell. However,I want the value in B4 to be 'performance,Quality' because 'EAM access issue' lies in both the type.

Comment: you will need Office 365 or later to do this with a formula, as it needs TEXTJOIN

Comment: @ScottCraner I have office 365. Please tell me how can i proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN() as an Array Formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$2:$K$3,A2)),$J$2:$J$3,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]